# How to specify a managed package key in a sfdx-project.json dependencies entry?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, packaging-2

It seems like it should be simple, but I have googled this and failed.

I'm writing a project using Packaging 2 in sfdx, and it depends on an old managed package. I've installed that package into my scratch org, but now I'm struggling to generate a package.

Here's my `sfdx-project.json`:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "id": "0HoXXXX",
      "versionNumber": "1.1.0.0",
      "versionName": "Initial",
      "ancestorId" : "05iXXX",
      "versionDescription": "Including Related List",
      "default": true,
      "dependencies": [{"subscriberPackageVersionId": "04tXXXX", "installationKey": "XXX"}]
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "xxxx",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "41.0"
}
```

When I run

```
sfdx force:package2:version:create -i 0HoXXX -d force-app/
```

I get the response:

```
(1) Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'installationKey'
```

Fair enough, but what is the right attribute for that? I can't find it from the documentation and none of my guesses have worked.

Comment: Might be worth cross posting over in the [Packaging 2 Beta](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000Lg5U) group.

Comment: Ah, I see you already have. 
https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000Lg5U&fId=0D53A00003R7c10

Comment: @DanielBallinger I've even opened a Case, too, but still no answer at all. I own the package I'm trying to use as dependency, so I might just roll a version with no password protection to get past this roadblock :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce have responded to this in the Packaging 2 Beta Trailblazer Community:

> Unfortunately what you're describing is a known outage for Packaging 2
>   right now. We have work in progress to resolve this but it obviously
>   has security implications which need to be carefully vetted.

Link (requires SF login):

https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?emkind=chatterCommentNotification&emtm=1518813023217&g=0F93A000000Lg5U&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&s1uid=0053A00000D4Cel

I've asked them to add it to the list of known limitations for Packaging 2: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_considerations.htm#package2-considerations